# Command that makes uppercase letters \mathcal and lowercase letters \mathfrak

Tags: math-fonts

Is there a way to make a command `\mixedfont{...}` that turns uppercase letters into `\mathcal` letters and lowercase ones into `\mathfrak`?

For example, `\mixedfont{AbcDef}` should give the same output as `\mathcal{A}\mathfrak{bc}\mathcal{D}\mathfrak{ef}`.

Comment: I’m curious what this is for. If it’s for a decorative text font, I wouldn’t want the math spacing, myself.

Comment: In math mode, I’d probably use one of the calligraphic alphabets that support lowercase.

Comment: So far, of the calligraphic fonts that support lowercase I never like the uppercase typeset. So I've been trying to mix and match a bit.

Comment: Hmm.. Doesn't sound very useful; if you would use this as a shortcut to write such symbols in just one font it seems likely to give problems for any paper that you might want to submit to a journal using its own style etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very trivial with a token cycle, which treats each token of the argument successively.  All characters in the input are processed, one at a time, through the `\Characterdirective`.  I assume that content is characters alone...all macros, spaces, and groups will be discarded from the input.  If punctuation finds its way into the input, it will just be echoed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,tokcycle}
\Characterdirective{%
  \tctestifcatnx A#1{\ifnum`#1<`[ \mathcal{#1}\else\mathfrak{#1}\fi}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\mixedfont[1]{\tokcyclexpress{#1}}
\begin{document}
$y = \mixedfont{AbcDef}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the token cycle to handle macros and groups, you just need to tell it what to do when it encounters them in the input.  And when you deal with macros that take arguments, you can no longer output the transformed tokens directly (as I did before), but instead gather them in a token list, and output the token list at the end.  If you try to output them directly, then the macros will be expecting their arguments before you process them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,tokcycle}
\newcommand\mixedfont[1]{\tokcycle
  {\tctestifcatnx A##1{\ifnum`##1<`[ \addcytoks{\mathcal{##1}}\else
   \addcytoks{\mathfrak{##1}}\fi}{\addcytoks{##1}}}% CHARACTERS
  {\processtoks{##1}}% GROUPS
  {\addcytoks{##1}}% MACROS
  {\addcytoks{##1}}% SPACES
  {#1}\the\cytoks}
\begin{document}
$y = \mixedfont{A\frac{b}{c}D^{2x+1}ef}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a two-liner with `expl3`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\calfrak}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  % search for strings of lowercase letters and replace them with \mathfrak{letters}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([a-z]+) } { \c{mathfrak}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_tmpa_tl
  % search for strings of lowercase letters and replace them with \mathcal{LETTERS}
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { ([A-Z]+) } { \c{mathcal}\cB\{\1\cE\} } \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\calfrak{AbcDef}$

\end{document}
```

[image]